# Shopify App development tutorials

Tags: shopify

I'm not sure if this is the right forum since I do not have a specific development question - but here goes :)

I'm looking into creating a Shopify app to use on my Shopify shop's frontend. 
I've been looking through the Shopify documentation and the API seems great - and it looks like a breeze to get up and running with an app (a private app at least).

But how do I use the app after I've created it? 
Let's say I create a new ASP.NET MVC site with a single controller (Home -> Index) that returns a view that simply says "Hello World". (in the future the controller would of course call the API and the View would do amazing stuff with the data etc.)

Now I would like to use this amazing site as an app on my Shopify shop's frontend. 
How in the world do I do this? :)

I can find a lot of tutorials about how to call the API and how to setup a private app in the Shopify admin - but how do I actually use this app on my frontend? 
I'm not looking for an explanation about public apps and OAuth etc. (although a tutorial for this would be great too) - but for starters just a tutorial on creating and using a private app.

Any great tutorials / Udemy courses / Pluralsight videos etc. out there I've missed?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do know that requests for tutorials don't get received very well here. Better to ask a specific development question (where you've already tried to get it to work), or use the Shopify forums.

Comment: Thanks - I've asked around in the Shopify forum as well as their support without getting a good answer. 
The only possible way I've found is to include some custom jquery that calls my app code and renders things based on this result. 
Not the best solution in the world - but it gets the job done. 
I would however like to know if anyone has a better approach. 
I might try to create a post based on a specific dev question. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Their API is very good, but the documentation for app development is so bad, I have spent more than half a day to find out how do I create some views and render it inside shopify, did you find some ?

Comment: You gotta good question, I have upvoted, but usually stack doesn't take care of such questions, although I have upvoted  !

Comment: Did you ever find any information on how to build an app? The only example I can find is the Ruby example.

Comment: Nope - however this might be useful: https://nozzlegear.com/shopify-development-handbook

Comment: I don't understand why this kind of questions should be considered as off-topic. Comon stack let people solve their problems

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would recommend is looking at the Shopify API libraries available. For example the [Shopify API Gem](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) in Ruby.

to get your app connected you need to do the following:

1) Get a developer's account on Shopify (partner account) and create an app.

2) Grab your API and secret key

3) follow the instruction on the API libraries like in the link provided (steps 1-7) and you should be able to get your app started.

(Essentially, grab the permanent token from Shopify and you will be able to make API calls and get all the data from the store you want).

Comment: how can we changed storefroent using shopify app

Comment: @RUC... You need to look at script tags. Basically, shopify allows apps to add JavaScript to a store. Your script must be https.

Comment: Thank You @Hussienk... I start to learn about script tags but i have problem with how to load my script in specific page

Answer (score 0):

Check the [shopify application proxy](https://docs.shopify.com/api/uiintegrations/application-proxies).

According to the doc, "an application proxy allows your application to add functionality to the frontend of a shop".

Comment: True - but an application proxy doesn't allow you to add functionality to an existing page. It only allows you to create your own URL's that's then proxied to your own server.
The only real way I've found is to do some jQuery magic - I just thought there would be a better best practice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it for a client or for your store, I'd suggest you to try with private apps.

I have built a marketplace model for a store which utilizes `/pages/` template to do the following:

1. Registration functionality for individual vendors. (Data stored in external database)
2. Login function for the users from above step.
3. A dashboard presentation of the collection the vendor, including all uploaded/approved products/individual product sales/revenue earned etc.

Point 3 requires **admin** requests to the shop and retrieve/post required data, and then present it on the front end. This can be only achieved using an app. In my case a simple private app (literally you require only the API KEY and APP PASSWORD) built on JavaScript functions did the trick.